# SNMP table index using octet string

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, asn.1, mib

I am working on an SNMP agent using net-snmp and developing a MIB for data held in tables.

I am considering using a table key based on a string of around 15 decimal digits.

Is it reasonable to implement this as an OCTET STRING index?

Even if I encode 2 digits per octet, it would be around 8 octets long.

With an OCTET STRING index, each octet would be added as a node to the OID.

I know that I can convert this to an integer(s), but the decimal digits could have leading zeros.

Are there any views or suggestions for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can put zeros into OCTET STRINGS, so yes you can do it that way.  OCTET STRINGS can contain binary data, and are encoded as simply a number into the OID.  The Net-SNMP API accepts not just a pointer to the char *, but also the length of the data returned.  And this is specifically because it's perfectly legal to have OCTET STRINGS with null values encoded within it.

On the OID side, if you had the string consisting of characters A, B 0, D it would generally be encoded as:

blah.blah.4.65.66.0.67

Where 4 is the length of the string.  If the OCTET STRING is marked as IMPLICIT, then the 4 would be left out.

You're encoding decimal digits into the string, so your values would be closer to things like 0x15, 0x04, 0x42, etc.  Those are just fine as well (you're building a binary string).

Whether you should do that or whether you should just plop the integers themselves down in the string is subject to debate but depends on what you're doing, and the bandwidth constraints of the environment, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if the length of the OCTET STRING (4 in the example above) is really necessary, as even if there are zero value octets (0x00) or even if the number of octets (or digits) is variable, OIDs and OCTET STRINGs have lengths associated with the actual values, i.e. they are not the same as C null-terminated strings. Also the index nodes are at the end of the OID sequence, so as long as you know what the stem of the OID is (blah.blah in the example above), you can know which parts of the OID constitute the index. I guess someone could encode a partial index, but that would be incorrect?

Comment: How an OID is encoded is very standardized.  If the index is specified as just an OCTET STRING, the length (4) MUST be in the OID (and tools like snmpwalk will expect it).  If the index is specified as an IMPLICIT OCTET STRING, then it must be the last index and the length MUST be omitted.

Comment: Are there any downloadable SNMP agents using a table with an index that is more than one node in an OID, such as an OCTET STRING? I would like to test SNMP gets/sets etc., including adding and deleting rows (using a rowStatus column). Ideally, if there is an agent I could just download and run... with the minimum amount of configuration and work. I get "no data available" from my ireasoning MIB browser when I send requests to Net-SNMP's snmpd (version 5.7.2) on my Linux box for any of the RFC 1213 tables that have "multi node" indices. Or perhaps I need to configure something for this to work?

Comment: For security reasons, yes you must configure Net-SNMP's agent before it'll return any data.  I'm assuming you're using v1 or v2c with a community string of "public".  Run `snmpconf -g basic_setup` and it'll walk you through creating a config file.